# How to Trigger a Different Intent in Dialogflow V1

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am well aware that Dialogflow V1 is being deprecated at the end of May 2020. However, I am wondering does anybody know how to trigger an intent in Dialogflow via webhook fulfillment? I have google searched the past few days looking everywhere and there seems to be a consensus that while events are available to trigger intent matching, they shouldn't be used. Right now, I have javascript function that is sending a webhook response with context out. I put that context into my dialogflow intent context input but when I run the agent, the intent is never triggered.

Javascript code:

```
function createTextResponse() {

    let response = {
        "speech": "Nice! Let's keep going.",
        "displayText": "displayed response",
        "contextOut": [
            {
              "name": "trythis",
              "lifespan": 5
            }
          ]
    }    

    return response;
}
```

Here is a picture with my contexts
[contexts in dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFF7L.png)
Been having a hard time with this lately and would appreciate any help/explanation in order so that I can move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remember that Intents represent *what the user says or does* and not how you react to them. So in general it doesn't make sense to "trigger an Intent". This is why the advice usually is to not use events - while they do make some sense in limited cases, those cases usually represent a user event and not your program trying to do something.

If you want your fulfillment to do something - just do it. Multiple Intent handlers can all call the same function to respond the same way.

Setting a Context does not automatically trigger an Intent. Setting the Input Context for an Intent restricts under what conditions that Intent can be triggered. While it still requires one of the training phrases to be matched, it also requires that all the Input Contexts be active.

Comment: thank you for the awesome explanation. that has made it clear to me that the best way to move forward is to increase my intents slightly based on user input I expect. Thanks again 

Comment: Great! If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what events are provided for. Just [invoke an event from your webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom#webhook).

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my question I'm trying to avoid events inasmuch as possible because I think events are based on more so edge cases and not my own particular case. I've tried events via my webhook but have been unsuccessful as I talk about above. It is best to involve multiple intent handles than to move forward with events, imo. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Maybe you can better state your use case and explain why you think events are not the right approach? Events can be used for anything that happens outside the conversation.